# microsoft-graph api users endpoint with filter provides NextLink Token Expired

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Removing my code as part of the equation, I was able to reproduce this through the Microsoft Graph API Explorer.

First, I Do a GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?`$filter=assignedLicenses%2fany(d%3ad%2fskuid+eq+ --actualySKUIDHere--)`

I get results back like

> {
>       "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
>       "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=assignedLicenses%2fany(d%3ad%2fskuid+eq+
>   --actualSKUIDHere-- )&$skiptoken=X%27 --actualtokenhere-- %27",
>       "value": [
>           {

I copy paste the nextLink into the API Explorer
ie.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?`$filter=assignedLicenses%2fany(d%3ad%2fskuid+eq+ --actualSKUIDHere-- )&$skiptoken=X%27 --actualtokenhere-- %27`

and it works with good results like above, but the next skipToken is shorter and copy & pasting it will result in the following

> {
>       "error": {
>           "code": "Directory_ExpiredPageToken",
>           "message": "The specified page token value has expired and can no longer be included in your request.",
>           "innerError": {
>               "request-id": "4cce84ea-83c5-403a-98d2-5ad5c948fcdc",
>               "date": "2020-02-03T21:04:43"
>           }
>       } }

I'm assuming this is a bug but wanted to post to see if anyone else has experienced this and has a resolution

Comment: I'm using the exact same filter as you. I get the first page fine but I get the same ExpiredPageToken when trying to get the next page.  Looks like a bug and I hope MS folks here can take a look.

Comment: Wanted to add that if your results are small enough you can increase the pagesize as a workaround ie:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=999&$filter=assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq [skuID])`

Comment: I'm experiencing the same when using the Microsoft Graph SDK for Java and opened an issue on their Github tracker: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues/368

Answer (score -1):

This was a temporary service issue which has been fixed since. You should not try to parse/modify the next link in your application, simply use it as provided by the service.